# $.scroll IE10/Firefox/Chrome differences?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer-10

Is there a difference between browsers for how $.scroll is called?

For example, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jdllama/2CrcC/13/) is a JSFiddle that I have; when it's run in Chrome, and you scroll the div up and down, multiple times, the tally increments rather slowly.

But in Internet Explorer 10, that tally skyrockets; I haven't gotten it consistent, but I can scroll once (via scroll wheel or using up and down on my keyboard) and it will jump between 11 and 13 at once.

I assume that IE10 calls it multiple times per scroll, but is there any way to sync these behaviors up?

The code:

```
var tally = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#scroller").scroll(function() {
        tally++;
        $("#tallyer").html(tally);
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't have any reference of this, but based on playing with `.scroll` myself; no. It is implemented different in the various browsers making it impossible to rely on without hacking/hardcoding something together.

Comment: What do you mean by "per scroll"? An arrow key press? A mouse wheel push? 1 pixel? 10 pixels? What if the user hits page up or down? Is it different if the scroll is animated? or "smooth"? You see the problem...

Comment: Gaurav, per scroll can mean any of those methods; mouse wheel, arrow key press, page up/down.

Animated vs. smooth doesn't seem to make a difference in Chrome.

EDIT: Hit Enter too soon! I also downloaded Firefox and used the same JSFiddle, and it acts the same as Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: What you are missing is that each of those methods produce a different amount of scrolling depending on browser and OS. Suppose you put your finger down and start moving it up and down on a phone at various different speeds. How many "scroll" events should that be? And why should that be standardized to be the same on every browser and OS, given that there is a performance / quality tradeoff?

Comment: Fair enough. I thought that at least desktop-wise that there would be consistency with how .scroll works internally, but the way you say it DOES make perfect sense. Thanks for the help!